# Transition Amplitude in Field Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, greens-functions

I am currently reading the "Quantum Field Theory" by Lewis Ryder.
In chapter 5 he is talking about path integrals and says that the transition amplitude $ \langle q_f t_f \vert q_i t_i\rangle $ is
$$
\langle q_f t_f \vert q_i t_i\rangle=N\int Dq\ \exp\bigg[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}L(q,\dot{q})dt\bigg]. \tag{5.15}
$$
But $L=T-V$ is the classical Lagrangian. Later in this book (chapter 6, pg 182) he is using this equation, but now in the Lagrangian he substitute the relativistic Lagrangian (Klein-Gordon Lagrangian) of a particle.

I can not find why this is true, because he use the classical energy-momentum relation to prove the above transition amplitude. Is there someone who know the connection or a paper who can give me some hints?

Comment: It is a known assumption and generalisation, upon which the propagators in QFT are defined. One proves the results for the one particle case and *believes* it is true in any other case, experimentally proving the outcomes eventually.

Comment: This can be derived. Any text on the "world-line formalism" will have a derivation of this.

Comment: Can you point to what precisely in the formal derivation  of eq. (5.15) in Ryder around (5.6)-(5.14) that is unsatisfactory?

Comment: My problem isn't there. My problem is in pg.187 where he uses the equation 5.15, which derived in the non-relativistic limit, and generalize it in the relativistic limit. I want to know why is this true and if i can prove that.

Comment: pg 187 around which eqs?

Comment: Under eq $6.1$ says :"L is the Klein-Gordon lagrangian (3.10)."

Comment: Ah. That's page 182 in the 2nd edition. Consider editing the post to explain more precisely your question.